# codeigniter redirect() not working

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

From /admin/login, i'm doing a jquery post to /admin/doLogin

```
public function doLogin()
{
    $this->load->model('admin_model');

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $data['user'] = $this->admin_model->do_login($email, $password);
    if($data['user'] == true)
    {
        redirect(base_url().'admin/');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect(base_url().'admin/login');
    }
}
```

Now, when $data['user'] == true, i stay on admin/login page.
In my network i see that /admin is loaded, but my page isn't refreshed to it.

I tried it with the codigniter redirect function, I also tried $this->index, I also tried to echo javascript window.location.href, but nothing is working. I always stay on that login page. Even though I always see they are loaded in my developerstool network.
Someone got an idea? Is it because i'm on localhost? I've no idea anymore..

EDIT:

```
$('#btn-login').click(function(){
    var email = $('#login-username').val();
    var password = $('#login-password').val();

    $.post(
        '/index.php/admin/doLogin/',
         { email: email, password: password },
         function(data) {
         }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As learn said, you can't use redirect in Ajax mode. You PHP script is called via Ajax, you can't redirect using PHP.

You must use Javascript callback :

```
public function doLogin()
{
    $this->load->model('admin_model');

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $data['user'] = $this->admin_model->do_login($email, $password);

    echo ($data['user'] ? 1 : 0);
}
```

And in your JS :

```
$.post(
    '/index.php/admin/doLogin/',
     { email: email, password: password },
     function(data) {
        var redirect = data == 1 ? 'admin' : 'admin/login';
        window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url() ?>'+ redirect;
     }
);
```

And why do you use Ajax if you PHP redirect ?

Comment: YOu are right, there was point doing ajax and then redirecting. I just do a normal form submit now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `base_url()`. You should just be using `redirect('your_controller/controller_function')`. Also you won't be redirected with PHP on an AJAX request, you have to do that client-side.

Comment: I tried that as well, but doesn't work. As i said, it seems to be loaded correctly but my browser is stuck on the login page.

Comment: Can you edit edit your post to show your javascript?